# Polymer.dart: drag and drop of elements inside ShadowDom

Tags: html, drag-and-drop, dart, dart-polymer

I am creating a sortable-list polymer element whose elements can be reordered using drag-n-drop operation. The problem is, I can't seem to get the elements inside a polymer element's shadowdom to react to drag-start event. However, interestingly, drag-over, drag-enter, drag-leave and drop events work fine.

Do elements inside shadowdom react to start-drag event?

You can find the code in the following link:

https://github.com/tejainece/sortable-list/tree/master/web/sortable-list

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look at http://www.polymer-project.org/docs/elements/core-elements.html#core-drag-drop how they do it but I assume you are running into this Chrome bug https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=264983. It is already marked as fixed but it takes a while until it lands in Dartium. If you have a recent Chrome version you can try if it works in Chrome.